# Converting Webm audio file to mp3 or ogg

Tags: javascript, chromebook, mediarecorder-api

I am currently working on a Chromebook application where I have to record an audio file with record/pause/resume features and then save the file in mp3 or ogg format. I am using mediaRecorder API to record the audio successfuly but the default file format Chrome supports is webm. I would like to know or get any help to convert/encode webm audio file to mp3 or ogg format using javascript to I could play it in any browser. I would be happy to share the code.

Comment: https://github.com/higuma/mp3-lame-encoder-js

Answer (score 3):

For everyone who is still looking for an answer. I was using AWS S3 to upload the files, so I used AWS Elastic Trascoder to convert the files on the AWS from webm to mp3 format.

Comment: it is realtime? i.e my scenario is sending voice messages in chat application like telegram or whatsapp. Does Transcoder takes time to do this task ?

Comment: Yes it takes time to get it converted.. Depending upon the size of the file few seconds.